# Where can I download / how can I install python 2.7 32-bit for Windows on a Windows 10 64-bit laptop? Required for Pepper Robot

Tags: python, python-2.7, pepper, choregraphe

I need this to use the Python SDK for Softbank's Pepper robot (as specified here https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao6/naoqi-developer-guide/sdks/python-sdk/python-sdk-installation-guide#python-install-guide).

I understand that I have to install the 32-bit version because the NAOqi-API has only been compiled for 32-bit systems, and installing the 64-bit version will throw errors.

I can't see a 32-bit version on the Python download page.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 2.7.18](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/)'s x86 / 32bit Windows installer: [python-2.7.18.msi](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18.msi) ([signature](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18.msi.asc))

**Context**

- 2.7.18 is the last release of python 2.7 [from April 20th, 2020](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/questions_and_answers.html#when-is-the-last-release-of-python-2-7-coming-out).
- January 1st, 2020 was the code freeze for 2.7.18.
- See also:

  - [PEP 373](https://peps.python.org/pep-0373/) for python 2.7, and
  - [PEP 404](https://peps.python.org/pep-0404/) (there will be no python 2.8).